# Passwords and Keys App: Is it possible to uncheck "Automatically Unlock Keyring whenever Im logged in"

Tags: 18.04, password, keyrings

(I think this is not a duplicate because the questions concerning unlocking the keyring are directed quite in the opposite direction...)

When unlocking a keyring (not the LOGIN one) in the "Passwords and Keys"-app preinstalled on Ubuntu, I get the possibility of ticking a checkbox saying "Automatically unlock this keyring whenever I'm logged in". I'm always unchecking it, because I want the keyring to be LOCKED, unless I explicitely unlock it. My question is:

Is there a possibility to uncheck this by default? I'm afraid of once forgetting to uncheck this and don't want the keyring to be open even when I'm logged in.

I'm still on 18.04.
[image]

Comment: You could probably uncheck it when you have elevated privileges (root)

Comment: You mean if I was logged in as root my decision would be remembered th enext time?

Comment: It should. Usually, anything done to your system in terminal saves the data to the system, it will not erase it unless you tell it to.